# Is the Alchemy Solana API worth it?

Tags: anchor, mainnet, devnet

I'm getting ready to deploy my dApp to mainnet soon. This is going to be the first time I deploy on mainnet and I'm confused on wether I will need to pay to run a Solana node or something like that. If I do, then I think I should use the `Alchemy supernode API` to manage the infrastructure but if I don't then what would be the point of this API? Is it as simple as changing everything that says `devnet` to `mainnet` and redeploying or will I need to continuously manage node infrastructure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public Solana rpc node is not intended to be used for production dapps. You should use a dedicated or private node when going into production.

The solana team have publicly stated this here:
https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints#mainnet-beta

> *The public RPC endpoints are not intended for production applications. Please use dedicated/private RPC servers when you launch your application, drop NFTs, etc. The public services are subject to abuse and rate limits may change without prior notice. Likewise, high-traffic websites may be blocked without prior notice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Meow it's very helpful. What have you personally used to manage a private Solana node when creating production dApps(if you have)?

Comment: I have not gotten that far, doing all my work on a test validator atm but if you have the budget for it do yourself the favor of going with at least 2 different providers so you have a fallback.